# Is there a way to return the variable name from Perl's max function?

Tags: perl, max

Using Perl's `List::Util` module, is there a way to return the variable name from `max()`, along with the actual value? Example:

```
my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;
my $c = 3;

my $max = max($a,$b,$c);
```

How can I get 3, as well as the variable name `$c`? My intention is to do something like:

```
#psuedocode
if(max is from $c) {
print "Max from C";
}
```

Or maybe a way to do this w/o `List::Util`?

Comment: You could create a hash, for example `%h = ( a => 1, b => 2, c=> 3 )` then loop through the keys and save both max value and corresponding key value

Comment: List::Util doesn't know that it got variables at all. It just sees a list. The values it gets for sorting/checking could also be one or more arrays, or the return value of a function. No luck there I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

```
sub pairmax {
    my $name = shift;
    my $max  = shift;
    while (@_) {
       if ($_[1] > $max) {
          $name = shift;
          $max  = shift;
       } else {
          shift;
          shift;
       }
    }

    return wantarray ? ($name,$max) : $name;
}

my $key_of_max = pairmax( a=>$a, b=>$b, c=>$c );

my ($key_of_max, $max) = pairmax( a=>$a, b=>$b, c=>$c );
```